# How to plot the NIR spectral signal from the hypercube data in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, satellite-image, spectral-python

I have the following data available from the hyperspectral imaging:

- cube_envi32.dat
- cube_envi32.hdr
- roi_masks.bmp

How can I plot the reflectance vs wavelength plot? Is there any sample python code that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot an arbitrary pixel, you can use the `spectral` module to read the pixel data and wavelengths (assuming wavelength metadata are in the ENVI header):

```
import spectral as spy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = spy.envi.open('cube_envi32.hdr')
(i, j) = (10, 10) # coordinates of pixel to display
plt.plot(img.bands.centers, img[i,j])
```

If you want to plot spectra interactively, see the `spectral` documentation [here](http://www.spectralpython.net/graphics.html).